# jsp /java application on facebook wall

Tags: java, facebook, jsp, servlets

i have an application in jsp...
with this aplication people can make answer so when people ask a question they send the text to a servlet that push the text into the db and come back with a jsp page. (like this http://www.fewcharts.com/DisplayQuestion?qId=62)
When i link this  page to a facebook post, it doesn't appear the question but only a link to the site (like www.fewcharts.com)
somebody can explain me why?

Comment: Because Facebook don't include random html on facebook.com

Comment: To tell Facebook what title, thumbnail image and description you want it to show for a particular URL, you have to implement Open Graph Meta Tags in your HTML document(s). http://ogp.me/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the sharing of Open Graph Stories on Facebok. You will not be able to run an entire application in the Feed but you can define how your website will be presented on the Facebook timeline by defining OG tags on your web pages which tells Facebook's crawler how to render your content of your website. Reference the documentation highlighted in the comment above and also the following for the implementation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started